# Stream Video from memory using Flask in Python3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I have been working on a project that generates a video ( 30fps ) and store it in memory.
I want it to stream to a browser using Flask but i do not want the video to store on drive even temporarily.
I tried using send_file, response method but didn't got any results.
Here is the app.py :-

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

def generate_video():
    return b'video data in bytes'

@app.route('/')
def home_page():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/static/a.mp4')
def stream_video():
    return Response(generate_video(), mimetype='video/mp4')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)
```

I have made the HTML Video Player using "PLYR" Script.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='plyr.css') }}"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="plyr-video" controls>
      <source src="/static/a.mp4" />
      <!--<source src="{{ url_for('static',filename='a.mp4') }}" />-->
    </video>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='plyr.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
      plyr.setup("#plyr-video");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main script for the web server in flask will allow you to Stream each frame through the /video_feed path. You can't send all the video in bytes:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, jsonify
from camera import VideoCamera
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

video_stream = VideoCamera()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def generate_video(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
   def video_feed():
        return Response(generate_video(video_stream),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port="5000", debug=True)
```

Then you need the VideoCamera class in witch you will handle each frame and where you can make every prediction or processing you want on the frames. I used OpenCv and the webcam stream here but you can change it with your video.
The **camera.py** file :

```
class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()        

    def get_frame(self):
        ret, frame = self.video.read()

        # DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH TENSORFLOW / KERAS AND OPENCV

        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)

        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

And the **index.html** file :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='plyr.css') }}"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
      <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also from https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask